# return value inside foreach

Tags: javascript, foreach, return

So this is very weird, I have a foreach function like this:

```
  let cookieValue = '';

  cookieList.forEach(function(cookieItem) {
    const cookieParts = cookieItem.split('=');
    const value = cookieParts[1];
    const key = cookieParts[0];
    if (key.trim() === cookieName) {
      cookieValue = value;
      return cookieValue;
    }
  });

  return cookieValue;
```

which works fine, however when I change the lines inside the if statement to a single line:

```
return value;
```

It returns undefined always.

Any ideas of what can be happening here?

Comment: The system completely ignores values returned from `.forEach()` callbacks.

Comment: How did you expect it to behave?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Take this simplified but equivalent example: `function foo() { function bar() { return 42; }; return 21; }`. What does `foo()` return?

Answer (score 2):

The return of forEach is ignored but you can use map and filter:

```
function getCookieValue(cookieList, cookieName) {
    var val = cookieList.map(function(cookieItem) {
        var cookieParts = cookieItem.split('=');
        var value = cookieParts[1];
        var key = cookieParts[0];
        return (key.trim() === cookieName) ? value : null;
    })
    .filter((value) => { return value != null })[0];
    return val;
}

let cookieValue = getCookieValue(["key1=val1", "key2=val2"], "key2"); // > "val2"
```

Comment: Array.find would be better

Answer (score 0):

Your code works "fine" at first because you're manually changing the value of `cookieValue`.

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't do anything with the returning value of the callback you pass to it.

For this case, I'd use a combination of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let cookieValue = cookieList.map(function(cookieItem) {
  const cookieParts = cookieItem.split('=');
  const value = cookieParts[1];
  const key = cookieParts[0];
  if (key.trim() !== cookieName) {
    return null;
  }
  return value;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a || b;
}, '');

return cookieValue;
```

Comment: Array.find would be better

Comment: It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: They both work but it is much harder to understand the map and reduce way.

Answer (score 0):

Your return value in the forEach function return in that function. By placing the return in the outer function, you return that value when that function is called. See this simplified example.

```
function x(){
    function y(){
        return 5 // Does not return in the x function
    }
    y() // = 5
    return 7
}
x() // =7
```

You seem like you are looking for Array.find.

```
let cookieValue = '';
return cookieList.find(function(cookieItem) {
  const cookieParts = cookieItem.split('=');
  const value = cookieParts[1];
  const key = cookieParts[0];
  return key.trim() === cookieName
});
```